# item = command.lower().split()[1] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I have to make a textbase game for my class. I'm new to coding. I have finished my game, and during testing, I found that if I type get map for get item, everything works fine. If I only type get and nothing else, I get this error

File "C:\Users\chris\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\TextBasedGame.py", line 34, in getitem
item = command.lower().split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

and don't know how to fix any help would be appreciated.

````
   if command.lower().split()[0] == 'get':
      item = command.lower().split()[1]
      if item in current_room['item']:
         current_room['item'].remove(item)
         items.append(item)
         if 'map' == item:
            print('!!!!You picked up the map press m to view. !!!!')
         else:
            print('You picked up {}'.format(item))
      else:
         print('Cant get {}, not found.'.format(item))
         print('-' * 25) ```
````

Comment: Can  you show what is the value of "command" when this error happens? It seems like your command has no white spaces as it should have

Comment: Took me a while to see it, but in the question he says that when he type "get" he get the error,

Answer (score 3):

When you try to get an item from a list in Python using square brackets, an `IndexError` will be raised if you try to get the value at an index that is out of bounds. In this case, only giving the command `"get"` means that when you call the `split()` method it will split your string up into a list containing one element at index `0`. Thus, when you try to access index `1`, it will be out of bounds.

You can fix this by checking the number of words that the command gets split into.

```py
if len(command.split()) < 2:
   print("Error, expected more command arguments")
```